# Cosa significa "per atti autentici o laicali"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Furto della Cassa Comunale, contenente somme vigenti, parte innumerario, parte in fede di 
>   credito; saccheggio in diverse case civili con appropriazione di somme, fede di credito, gioje, oggetti d'oro e di argento accompagnato da incendî di libri creditorî e di ogni documento appartenente a fortune private; devastazione a frutta, a ricolta, nei campi estesa e generalizzata per eserzione degli anarchisti; appropriazione di case, e di poderi precedentemente per sentenza pendente; o volontariamente, e **per atti autentici o laicali**, scrocco di somme per componende, e minacce di danno, o di vita, arresti arbitrarii, ed ogni altra abusiva escandescenza, e tutto questo iniziato al grido di Viva Vittorio Emmanuele - Viva Garibaldi, e all'ombra del Vessillo della rigenerazione, che aveva servito di mezzo a disarmare preventivamente, ed agglomerare vittorie designate; come le prime ad essere immolate, e che dovevan essere seguite da altre, cui fortuite circostanze trovarono, e che dovevano formare i prodromi di un numero di reati e di scelleraggini, poscia parte consumati, parte per divina misericordia non commessi.

Si tratta di parte di un documento emesso dalla     Commissione Speciale di Patti  nel 1860.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione  "per atti autentici o laicali" che appare nel testo. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Dove è ambientato il romanzo e in che periodo? Per caso nello Stato della Chiesa?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: In Sicilia durante il Risorgimento. Infatti si tratta di un documento storico vero emesso dalla [Commissione Speciale di Patti](http://www.amiciziafraipopoli.org/documenti-siino-alcara.htm) dopo i fatti di Alcàra Li Fusi.

Comment: per atto autentico credo si intenda un atto pubblico (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atto_pubblico) mi sfugge però il significato dell'aggettivo "laicale" in questo contesto (laico = non religioso)